# Architecture choice: ESB and EJB

Tags: ejb, websphere, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.0, esb

I am building a new Java EE application (thin client), and here is the application layers:

- The application presentation will be with JSF2 / Spring webflow and RichFaces 4
- The businees layer will be with EJB 3
- The Persistance layer will be with JPA2 - Hibernate implementation

The application will run on Websphere Appliccation server.

The company owns Websephre Message Broker as an ESB.

I have got two choices, and i am trying to find out the best depending on the scalability, maintenance, performance, Best practices and entreprise architecture design, for each of them:

1. Deploy the business EJB3 Services on the ESB and deploy the presentation layer on a dedicated server: The presentation Layer will call the business services through the ESB
2. Deploy the EJB services on a dedicated WAS and deploy the presentation layer on a dedicated server: The presentation Layer will call directely the EJB services without using the ESB

Comment: Do you need all of that stack or are you going to use it because the company paid for it? Each technology you mentioned has an implicit cost that will make your project more difficult to implement and maintain. Personally, I wouldn't use EJB or an ESB, I prefer simplicity over complexity (and headaches)

Comment: Oh, and another comment, if you're asking if this is the correct architecture, then definitely is not the right choice. In my experience, you use an ESB or EJBs when you have tried other approaches and all failed, so the last resource is one of these 2 technologies.

Comment: EJB3 is not a bad architecture for middleware layer. It has a lot of benefits, security, transaction management, simplicity...  Now we have 2 options: call EJB through ESB from JSF or call directely the EJB from JSF

Comment: Lots of comments from people who don't know about enterprise ESB design patterns.   I'd go with someone who works in this space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends (as always :) ) If you plan to extend your application in the future and integrate it with other clients apart from the JSF client then ESB would be a viable solution. Else keep the things simple, i.e. everything in an application server. In case you proceed with the ESB I recommend you moving the EJB layer to the application server and exposing your application from the ESB as web services.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my rec.... build your app on WAS using the architectural decisions you've made.    For integration of your app to the ESB, I would vote for JMS or WebSphere MQ.  You could opt for web services but as your enterprise architecture team would most likely say.... you need to have time independent communications with confirmed delivery.

If you want to also see how this all works, I would look at the IBM SOA Design Patterns or feel free to read my Redbook (IBM SOA Retail Design Patterns) for an idea of how to glue apps to the ESB.